# How to fix GGSankey Error: unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

Tags: r, dataframe, list, ggplot2

I have been using the same code for months to create a graph using ggsankey. But today I ran the code and for some reason I was getting an error message. I can't remember if I changed anything in the dataframe, but I don't think I did.

Here is a sample of the dataframe:

```
df = structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), levels = c("Method_Group", "Topic"), class = "factor"), 
    node = list(c("mobile", "receiver"), "Behavioural Ecology", 
        c("mobile", "receiver"), "Conservation Measures", c("animal", 
        "borne", "no", "receiver"), "Other Drivers", c("stationary", 
        "receiver"), "Behavioural Ecology", c("stationary", "receiver"
        ), "Behavioural Ecology", c("stationary", "receiver"), 
        "Reproductive Ecology", c("stationary", "receiver"), 
        "Other Drivers", c("stationary", "receiver"), "Behavioural Ecology", 
        c("stationary", "receiver"), "Methodological", c("baited", 
        "receiver"), "Behavioural Ecology", c("baited", "receiver"
        ), "Methodological", c("baited", "receiver"), "Reproductive Ecology", 
        c("baited", "receiver")), next_x = structure(c(2L, NA, 
    2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
    NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L), levels = c("Method_Group", 
    "Topic"), class = "factor"), next_node = list("Behavioural Ecology", 
        NULL, "Conservation Measures", NULL, "Other Drivers", 
        NULL, "Behavioural Ecology", NULL, "Behavioural Ecology", 
        NULL, "Reproductive Ecology", NULL, "Other Drivers", 
        NULL, "Behavioural Ecology", NULL, "Methodological", 
        NULL, "Behavioural Ecology", NULL, "Methodological", 
        NULL, "Reproductive Ecology", NULL, "Landuse Management")), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and this is code I am running to make the ggsankey plot - I have additional code to make it formatted properly, but this is where I am getting the error.

```
library("viridis")
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library("ggalluvial")
library(stringr)
library("ggh4x")
library(forcats)
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyr)
library("tokenizers")
library(ggsankey)
remotes::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
#sorry for providing all the libraries, I can't remember which ones are needed for this code, and I can't run it to find out

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node, fill = factor(node), label = node)) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 1, node.color = "black",show.legend = FALSE, width=0.40) +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 5, color = "black", fill= "white") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()
        , axis.text.y = element_blank()
        , axis.text.x = element_blank()
        , axis.ticks = element_blank()  
        , panel.grid = element_blank())+
  #scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "inferno")
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE)
```

As I mention above it use to work fine. Now when I run the code I get this error message:

```
Error in `geom_sankey()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `order()`:
! unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

When I look online others mention that the problem it is a list format, so I tried running this code before I use the dataframe in the ggplot code I provided

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, unlist))
```

But this just gives me more errors. Any idea how to fix this?

For reference the final product looks like this after I've used my additional code that formats it better. But the shape and flow should look something similar
[image]

Comment: Do you have an image of the final sankey diagram which used to print; i.e. the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these modifications get you to the intended result?

1. turn the `node` elements into strings
2. replace the `next_node` `NULL` values to `NA`s

Which results in a sankey diagram.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsankey)
library(viridis)
library(dplyr)


df1 <- 
  df |> 
  dplyr::rowwise() |> 
  dplyr::mutate(node = paste(unlist(node), collapse = "-"),
                next_node = ifelse(is.null(next_node), NA, next_node))
  
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node, fill = factor(node), label = node)) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 1, node.color = "black",show.legend = FALSE, width=0.40) +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 5, color = "black", fill= "white") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()
        , axis.text.y = element_blank()
        , axis.text.x = element_blank()
        , axis.ticks = element_blank()
        , panel.grid = element_blank())+
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>